# Can't get the value of a function inside an object using socketIO

Tags: javascript, function, object, socket.io

I'm trying to pass an object from my socket file to my html file and print out a function value thats located inside it. but I keep getting this error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'confirmed' of undefined

socket.js

```
function querys() {
                var queryString1 = 'SELECT contacts.id, userId, contactId, confirmed, username FROM contacts LEFT JOIN users on contacts.contactId = users.id WHERE userId = ?';
                var buddy = new Object();

                connection.query(queryString1,[id], function(err, rows, fields) {//look for all requests started by another user
                    if (err) throw err;
                    for (var i in rows) {
                        buddy[i] = (
                            {
                                id : rows[i].contactId, 
                                username : rows[i].username, 
                                sender : false, 
                                connectionId : rows[i].id,
                                confirmed : function() {
                                    if(rows[i].confirmed == 0)
                                        return false;
                                    else
                                        return true;
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                    socket.emit('print', buddy);                    
                });
            }
```

function in html file

```
socket.on('print', function(buddy) {
                    alert(buddy[0].confirmed());
                }
```

Strange thing is that it does print the other values of the object if you ask it to but I cant seem to print out the function inside the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't transmit functions over socket.io, only json data. I'd recommend just sending `confirmed` as a boolean.